# How fetch array value in nested ngFor?

Tags: angular

```
Error:AppComponent.html:16 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (AppComponent.html:16)
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormArray } from '@angular/forms'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app';
  signupForm: FormGroup;
  arr;
  ngOnInit() {

    this.arr = ["id", "name", "weight", "quantity"];

    this.signupForm = new FormGroup({
      'id': new FormArray([new FormControl('1'), new FormControl('2')]),
      'name': new FormArray([new FormControl('Beans'), new FormControl('Soup')]),
      'weight': new FormArray([new FormControl('100'), new FormControl('125')]),
      'quantity': new FormArray([new FormControl('60'), new FormControl('20')])
    });
    console.log(this.arr[0]);
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <form [formGroup]="signupForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>S.no</td>
              <td>NAME</td>
              <td>WEIGHT</td>
              <td>QUANTITY</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <div *ngFor="let i of arr">
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div *ngFor="let val of signupForm.controls.i.controls">{{val.value}}</div>
               </td>
              </tr>
            </div>

          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to fetch the i value and pass it in `*ngFor="let val of signupForm.controls.i.controls`

Comment: `signupForm.controls[i]controls`, I assume.

Comment: No, that is not working @Cerbrus

Comment: @Cerbrus probably meant `signupForm.controls[i].controls`

Comment: I add this signupForm.controls.[i].controls before, but now your signupForm.controls[i].controls worked! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each formArray, you can loop through it by using `signupForm.get(i).value` in the inside `*ngFor` loop. (you still need the outside `*ngFor` as you have in code). Then access the element using `{{ val }}` instead of `{{ val.value }}`.

Using the `get`ters is preferred over directly accessing `controls` of a form when it comes to `aot` compilation based on [this](https://github.com/qdouble/angular-webpack2-starter#aot--donts).

**EDIT**

To get the UI right as per your comments, you probably have to restructure your template a bit to something like this,

```
<table class="table">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <td>S.no</td>
   <td>NAME</td>
   <td>WEIGHT</td>
   <td>QUANTITY</td>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor = "let i of signupForm.get('id').value; let k = index">
   <td>{{ signupForm.get('id').value[k] }}</td>
   <td>{{ signupForm.get('name').value[k] }}</td>
   <td>{{ signupForm.get('weight').value[k] }}</td>
   <td>{{ signupForm.get('quantity').value[k] }}</td>
  </tr>                                
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Here, the initial array `let i of signupForm.get('id').value` is used to know the length of each `formArray`. you can use other means if you know to get an array with the right length of elements for that array.

Comment: No,ERror!

Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token ., expected identifier or keyword at column 23 in [let val of signupForm..get(i).value

Comment: buddy you have **2 dots** here (after `signupForm`): `let val of signupForm..get(i).value` !! Remove one. :)

Comment: error is gone but no ouput of array elements, just table titles are showing

Comment: access the elements using `{{ val }}` instead of `{{ val.value }}`.

Comment: already tried but all the elements are coming in different row! Why??

Comment: Okay, for that you need to restructure your template a bit. Making an answer now

Comment: <tr *ngFor = "let i of arr"><td *ngFor="let val of signupForm.get(i).value">{{val}}</td></tr>
I deleted all the div but now, rowsdata is displayed in column.

Comment: See my updated answer. Please mark, if it helped. Thanks :)

Comment: Problem Solved!! Thank you very much! :). I was struggling for the last 6 hours

Comment: Actually, nothing. That's what I meant by the last paragraph in my updated answer. You are iterating over an array of length equal to the length of the formArray you have initialized. In your case the length is 2 (from your code). But you only need the index value to be used within your loop, so that is why I mentioned if you have an array you can relate to in your component for the looping where each element is simply ascending integers starting from '0', then you can get rid of the `k = index` assignment. Otherwise, you would need that index assignment where the number of iterations is...

Comment: ...determined by the length of the formArray computed by `signupForm.get('id').value`

Comment: 2 things - 1) I cannot see the relevant files in this provided [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BzDRTfxQgCN9TW1SVkZqT3FLdnM) (only a module.ts file (downloading as  video file ??) and an angular-cli.json file). 2) It's probably better to create a new question for this. You can link this problem (if related and helps to crack it down easily). Please share the updated links and preferably a new question. Thanks :)

Comment: I want add new values to FormArray by calling hitadd() function. [ https://github.com/RishabhSaluja/ang ].I was just updating..

Comment: Please untangle this question from this post. This is definitely not related to the OP in here. Let me know. It seems like the commented out section in the component for `hitAdd()` is creating the problem for you. I will respond further in the new post (if you create one). Thanks